# Getting a Confirmation Box to appear and get its value in the code behind

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, confirmation

Here's what I want to do. I have a form that the user fills out (creating sections and subsections) and when they click save, I want to check the database to see if they have named a section the same as one that already exists. If they have, I want to get a confirmation from them to let them know they wil create a duplicate if they proceed. If they click yes, I need to continue, else I need to abort. Here is some psuedocode for what I have so far.

```
 protected void SaveButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (CheckForDuplicates())
        {
            //proceed normally
        }
    }
}

private bool CheckForDuplicates()
{
    //check database

            if (/*there are duplicates*/)
            {
                string message = "A duplicate name exists. Would you like to continue?";
                string scriptString = "<script language='javascript' 
                    type='text/javascript'>" + "return confirm('" + message + "');</script>";

                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), 
                    "script", scriptString, false);

                //here i would like to return their confirmation
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

All help is appreciated and thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Javascript such that if user confirms, you can call the JavaScript `__doPostBack('','UserConfirmed');` function.  Just add the logic in your codebehind along with your confirmation logic that you are registering with the ScriptManager .  When the postback occurs, you can then check to ensure that the postback was, in fact, initiated by the user's confirmation (as opposed to some other action on the page):

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string parameter = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
  //if parameter equals "UserConfirmed"
  //       User confirmed, so do whatever
  //
}
```

Information on `__doPostBack`: [Understanding the JavaScript __doPostBack Function](http://aspalliance.com/895_Understanding_the_JavaScript___doPostBack_Function)

Comment: Thanks! I was a little confused with the _doPostBack, but your link really helped.